# How to set classpath of tomcat in ubuntu

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, web-applications

I have installed Tomcat in Ubuntu 14. It's working, but the servet class in my application shows 6 errors. This is due to the classpath. I know how to set the classpath in Windows. Can you please tell me how to set the classpath in Ubuntu?

Comment: Are you sure you want to do this. A WAR should be self contained.

Comment: In addition to @Raedwald comment, I think you should explain how are you building your WAR and what are the errors. Tomcat follows Servlet's specifications its behavior shouldn't be spoiled.